# If statement cannot implicitly convert type to bool?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am testing if a variable is set to bool in C# through an `if` statement. For some reason it says "Cannot implicitly convert type to bool".

```cs
if (s4 = null) {
    System.Console.WriteLine("Student Not Found");
} else {
    System.Console.WriteLine($"{s4.FirstName} {s4.LastName} {s4.Major?.Description}");
    var db = new AppEfDbContext();
}
```

Comment: 'if (s4 == null) {'

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! You need to use `==`, not `=`, i.e. `s4 == null`.

Comment: to set a variable to a value you use '=', for example: 'int x = 0;'. in order to compare two values you use '==', for example 'if (x == 0)'.

Comment: What is type of s4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `=`.  The `=` is assignment, and comparison is `==`

```
if (s4 == null) {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Student Not Found");
            } else {
                System.Console.WriteLine($"{s4.FirstName} {s4.LastName} {s4.Major?.Description}");
                var db = new AppEfDbContext();
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Boolean Expressions must be done with `==` so the code must look like this:

```cs
if (s4 == null) {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Student Not Found");
            } else {
                System.Console.WriteLine($"{s4.FirstName} {s4.LastName} {s4.Major?.Description}");
                var db = new AppEfDbContext();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `==` instead of `=` in if condition.

[`=` : Assignment Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/assignment-operator)

> The assignment operator = assigns the value of its right-hand operand to a variable

[`==` :  Equality operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/equality-operators)

> Equality operators check if their operands are equal or not.

```
if (s4 == null) { 
      //^ this was missing
    System.Console.WriteLine("Student Not Found");
} else {
    System.Console.WriteLine($"{s4.FirstName} {s4.LastName} {s4.Major?.Description}");
    var db = new AppEfDbContext();
}
```